# How can I change the validation language on Windows Azure Web Site (asp.net mvc4)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, azure-web-app-service

I've already added `<globalization culture="de-DE" uiCulture="de-DE" />` to my Web.config. I added `@Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` to my testview and it shows de-DE. So, all seems fine.

But the validation message is still in English, e.g.

> The Input field is required.

What is my mistake?

Comment: Did you figure it out ?

Comment: No. Currently i use custom attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem.

I suppose that "Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 Language Pack" is not installed on Azure "Web sites". It seems using an "Azure cloud project" is an option as you can then configure IIS directly.

Another solution is to wait for Microsoft to include Language Pack support in Azure...

Personnaly, I have decided to override the main attributes. Most trickiests are [Required] and [Regex]. See below (Loc is my own Localization function as I am using gettext)

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Ic.DataAnnotations
{
    public class RequiredLoc : RequiredAttribute, IClientValidatable
    {

        public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata,
            ControllerContext context)
        {
            yield return new ModelClientValidationRule
            {
                ErrorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(metadata.DisplayName),
                ValidationType = "required"
            };
        }

        public override string FormatErrorMessage(string message)
        {
            base.FormatErrorMessage(message);
            return Localizer.Loc("Le champs '%1' est requis.", message);
        }
    }

}
```

For regular expressions:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Globalization;

namespace Ic.DataAnnotations
{
    public class RegularExpressionLoc : RegularExpressionAttribute
    {
        private readonly string _errorMessage;

        public RegularExpressionLoc(string errorMessage, string pattern)
            : base(pattern)
        {
            _errorMessage = errorMessage;
        }

        public override string FormatErrorMessage(string input)
        {
            return Localizer.Loc(_errorMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

And

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Ic.DataAnnotations
{
    public class RegularExpressionValidator : DataAnnotationsModelValidator<RegularExpressionAttribute>
    {
        private readonly string _message;
        private readonly string _pattern;

        public RegularExpressionValidator(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context, RegularExpressionAttribute attribute)
            : base(metadata, context, attribute)
        {
            _pattern = attribute.Pattern;
            _message = attribute.FormatErrorMessage("");
        }

        public override IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules()
        {
            var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule
            {
                ErrorMessage = _message,
                ValidationType = "regex"
            };

            rule.ValidationParameters.Add("pattern", _pattern);

            return new[] { rule };
        }
    }
}
```

And in Global.asax

```
  DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(RegularExpressionLoc), typeof(RegularExpressionValidator));
```